# octal expansion difference between [ and [[?

Tags: bash, sh, octal

As far as I had known, `[[` and `[` can be expected to behave mostly the same, taking into account a few extra features `[[` has. But recently I noticed a discrepancy in how bash treats octal expansions:

```
$ b=010; echo $((b))
8
$ [[ $b -eq 8 ]]; echo $?
0
```

but

```
$ [ $b -eq 8 ]; echo $?
1
$ test $b -eq 8; echo $?
1
$ [ $b -eq 10 ]; echo $?
0
```

Why does the latter expression drop the auto octal conversion? Expressions like `-eq` are "Arithmetic" according to `help test` in Bash and the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions), and further according to the next section of the reference manual constants with a leading zero can be treated as octal.

POSIX sh is a little less clear [on the subject](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_05): Even though POSIX arithmetic expressions still expand leading-zero integers to their octal value, it refers to `-eq` expressions in `test` as *algebraic*, not *arithmetic*.

Is there any documentation or evidence to suggest that bash makes a distinction between `[[` and `[` for octal expansion on purpose, or is it just an accidental feature?

Comment: +1; but I note that although `-eq` is described as an "arithmetic binary operator", its arguments are *not* described as "arithmetic expressions". So, for example, `[ b -eq 10 ]` does not expand the shell parameter `$b`. So while it certainly would make more sense for that operator to treat `010` as meaning 8 rather than 10, I don't see anything in the manual that really contradicts the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: `[[ b -eq 8 ]]` seems to be equivalent to `(( b == 8 ))` (you can omit the `$`). The documentation doesn't seem to say so.

Comment: @choroba good point, I hadn't even realized that `[[ x -eq y ]]` expands x and y just like `(( ))` expressions.

Comment: Since you brought it up, I tried `[[ 9-1 -eq b ]]` and the exit status was 0. So inside `[[ … -eq … ]]` bash clearly infers an arithmetic context. Go figure.

Comment: Another context where Bash does not recognize octal constants, and treats `010` as meaning 10, is file descriptors during redirection. That part *is* explicitly specified by POSIX (which requires a "decimal number").

Comment: This is a well-known feature (or should be), and it's also known that arithmetic context (be it with `((...))` or `[[ ... -eq ... ]]`)  can lead to code injection. E.g., a funny one: `a='a[$(ls >&2)]'; if [[ $a -eq 42 ]]; then echo yes; fi`.

Comment: Moreover, `[[` is a keyword and `[` is a builtin; this leads to subtle differences in the way code is parsed; you can't do `a=[[; $a 42 = 42 ]] && echo yes` but you can do `a=[; $a 42 = 42 ] && echo yes`.

Comment: The difference is even more visible as you try use `$x=0x10; echo $((x));[[ $x -eq 16 ]]; echo $? ; [ $x -eq 16 ]; echo $?` - leads to error: `integer expression expected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[ is known as the extended test command and behaves as ksh88, you can find an elaboration here: 
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS

Also if you need to be sure of the base in bash you can use the # base operator like this:

```
b=010; echo $((10#$b))
10
b=10; echo $((8#$b)
8
b=013; echo $((8#$b))
11
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll +1 this just because TLDP link actually mentions the discrepancy in my question directly. That said, ksh93 apparently doesn't do octal expansion in `$(( ))`, which makes it depart even from POSIX sh. (I don't have ksh88 handy, but maybe someone with it can comment.)

Comment: Oh weird, ksh93 does treat literals with leading zeros as octal, but does not do the same on expansion. `echo $((010)) -> 8`, but `x=010;echo $((x)) -> 10`. I could see how this behavior could be considered POSIX compliant.

Comment: Not that way, but if you `x=010;echo $(($x))` you should get 8.

Comment: That is actually confusing. I mean you can clearly tell how ksh is lexing the expression, but POSIX says _The shell shall expand all tokens in the [arithmetic] expression for parameter expansion, command substitution, and quote removal._ It doesn't say that it should lex `$x` as an independent expansion, and then treat the post-expansion `010` as an octal literal.

Comment: I agree it seems quirky and not according to the POSIX statement you quoted. Its best to check the source code if you really want to see whats going on - but without doing that - I would guess that `ksh` is expanding the variable prior to the expression, so in the case of `$x` it doesn't know/care that `$x` is part of an arithmetic expression it is a first pass expansion and simply expands it to the string literal 010. In the second case `x` it looks like the expansion is handled by a different code segment where it is automatically converted to decimal.